# C++ Dynamic Array for Class Object of different variable types

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to write a dynamic array that will allow me to enter a unique number of vehicles through the function addVehicle but im struggling on how to use the array and add items to it.

I read that dynamic arrays are created through the use of a vector function but im a bit confused on how it works, additionally as you can see my vehicle class has different variable types, will that interfere?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//Silo Storage System

class Silo {
    public:
        std::string name;
        int currentVolume;
        int storageVolume;
};

class Vehicle {
    public:
        std::string model;
        int capacity;
};


void addVehicle(std::vector<vehicle>& vehicle){
    vehicle v;

    
    //std::cout << "Please specify number of vehicles to add" << endl;
    
    std::cout << "Please specify the vehicle model" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> v.model;
    std::cout << "Please specify the load capacity" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> v.capacity;
    
    vehicle.push_back(v);
};


int main() {
    
    Silo depoSilos[3] = {
    {"Silo 1 - Aggregate", 1400,  40000},
    {"Silo 2 - Aggregate", 2300,  20000},
    {"Silo 3 - Aggregate", 11000,  40000}
    };
    
    std::cout << "No. of available silos: " << *(&depoSilos + 1) - depoSilos << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0;i < *(&depoSilos + 1) - depoSilos; i++) {
        std::cout << depoSilos[i].name << " is " << static_cast<double>(depoSilos[i].currentVolume) / static_cast<double>(depoSilos[i].storageVolume) * 100 <<
        "% full." << " Max capacity: " << depoSilos[i].storageVolume << std::endl;
    };

    std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles;
    addVehicle(vehicles);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile (`std::vector<vehicle>` is incorrect; c++ is case sensitive).

Comment: @Atmo `push_back` copies

Comment: `std::vector` is a class, not a function. Also in order to improve the quality of your question, please describe exactly what you are trying to achieve, and what are the problems/errors that you encounter.

Comment: @Vivick Yes my bad, I was focused on the errors and got too "motivated"...

Comment: `std::vector<vehicle>& vehicle`: `vehicle` is not a proper name for a collection of `Vehicle`s. At least add a `s` suffix to denote a collection.

Comment: `*(&depoSilos + 1)` has undefined behaviour; you are not allowed to dereference `&depoSilos + 1`. Use `std::size(depoSilos)`, or an `array`, or a `vector`.

Comment: What kind of "interference" are you worried about?

Comment: Please edit and clarify your question. What are the "different variable types" you are worried about? As you probably observed, `vehicles.push_back(v);` should work out of the box, without any further effort. What you are doing with `depoSilos`, is entirely unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this, you'll need to:

1. Prompt the user for the number of vehicles to create
2. Use that to prepare your vector
3. Prompt the user for the vehicle details, in a loop

Here's how it could look like:

```
void addVehicle(std::vector<Vehicle>& vehicles){
    int vehiclesCount = 0;
    
    std::cout << "Please specify number of vehicles to add" << endl;
    std::cin >> vehiclesCount;

    // or some other validation logic for the vehiclesCount
    if (vehiclesCount <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    // pre-allocate memory all at once (only done if necessary)
    vehicles.reserve(vehiclesCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < vehiclesCount; ++i) {
      vehicle v;
      std::cout << "Please specify the vehicle model" << std::endl;
      std::cin >> v.model;
      std::cout << "Please specify the load capacity" << std::endl;
      std::cin >> v.capacity;
    
      vehicle.push_back(v);
    }
}
```

Then, you might also want to turn your `class`es with only `public` members into `struct` which will allow them to be aggregates, and distinguished as such:

```
struct Silo {
    std::string name;
    int currentVolume;
    int storageVolume;
};

struct Vehicle {
    std::string model;
    int capacity;
};
```

You might also want to replace you C-style array with a C++ `std::array`. Since you classes into aggregate structs, you'll also benefit from the aggregate initialization syntax:

```
std::array<Silo, 3> depoSilos = {
    {"Silo 1 - Aggregate", 1400,  40000},
    {"Silo 2 - Aggregate", 2300,  20000},
    {"Silo 3 - Aggregate", 11000,  40000}
};
```

To get the size of a container, you'll prefer using `std::size` or the dedicated member function:

```
std::cout << "No. of available silos: " << std::size(depoSilos) << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < std::size(depoSilos); ++i) {
// [...]
```

Comment: You copy-pasted `std::vector<vehicle>` with typo from the question. Also using `std::cin` explicitly inside a function makes it untestable, good approach would be to accept `std::istream&` in some parsing function, and then pass `std::cin` in main, and something else (maybe `std::fstream`) in tests. Anyway I think it's hard to answer this question without OP clarifying first what is his exact goal.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix user input with backend logic, pass the item to the method:

```
void addVehicle(std::vector<Vehicle>& vehicles, Vehicle v){
    vehicles.push_back(v);
};
```

and let's call the method inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0;i < *(&depoSilos + 1) - depoSilos; i++) {
    Vehicle v;
    std::cout << "Please specify the vehicle model" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> v.model;
    std::cout << "Please specify the load capacity" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> v.capacity;    
    addVehicle(vehicles, v);
};
```

Of course, initialize `vehicles` properly before the loop.